# Nodata value making holes in merged GeoTIFFs in QGIS?

Tags: qgis-3, geotiff-tiff, merge, nodata

I am trying to remove black borders around the edge of a GeoTIFF. The Black border around the GeoTIFF has an RGB value of `(0,0,0)`. I have tried assigning `0` as a `"No Data"` value to the tiff, but QGIS then makes all pixels which contain a `0` such as `(0,54,76)` into `"No Data"` pixels. This leaves holes in the map.

Is there a way of only classifying a `"No Data"` pixel if `0` is found across all 3 RGB bands on a pixel(pure black pixel)?

I am using the latest version of QGIS 3.8 Zanzibar. Here are 2 screenshots to clarify the situation.

[Image of file for merging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8sMx.png)

[image: example]

Answer (score -1):

In the transparency layer properties tab there is a option to set in a no data value for each color value of a pixel. Fill in 0,0,0 for R,G,B and then transparency 100, this only turns the black pixels transparent.